# import Product lines direct to opportunity

Tags: community, data-loader, import

we are still in the implementation phase of sales force and my team role is pre-sales. so basically, we add the product line items to opportunities. the problem is as per our implementer feedback, we have to select products inside the opportunity from product catalogs. and since we might have a huge Bill of material, this is a time-consuming process, I was wondering if we can import a BoQ directly to an opportunity from csv file or through a tool?

Comment: Have you explored this:- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000316582&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1

Comment: Also, You can try automating it using apex class.